# ng-repeat filter is empty loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i do the following ng-repeat loop and it works well!

```
<div ng-repeat="einschItem in einschaetzungen.alldata | filter: { savedatum: lolatage[tagarrayindex].tagestring } | orderBy : '-savetimestamp'">
```

now i want to check if the filtered is empty, so i searched and found this way how it should solve my problem.

```
<div ng-repeat="einschItem in einschaetzungen.alldata = (values | filter: { savedatum: lolatage[tagarrayindex].tagestring } | orderBy : '-savetimestamp')">

{{values.length}}
```

But if use this code i don't get any results in the loop anymore, the "einschItem" ist empty.

thanks!

i use angular v1.4.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *probably* want here is to alias the results of the repeat.  From the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> `variable in expression as alias_expression` – You can also provide an optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:x as results` will store the fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items have been processed through the filter.
>
> Please note that `as [variable name]` is not an operator but rather a part of ngRepeat micro-syntax so it can be used only at the end (and not as operator, inside an expression).
>
> For example: `item in items | filter : x | orderBy : order | limitTo : limit as results`.

So in your case, you can use:

```
<div ng-repeat="einschItem in einschaetzungen.alldata | 
               filter: { savedatum: lolatage[tagarrayindex].tagestring } |
               orderBy : '-savetimestamp' 
               as filteredItems">

{{filteredItems.length}}
```

Note that this is functionally the same as the syntax provided in the other answer to the question;  This is just an alternative provided by the ngRepeat micro-syntax.

Comment: thanks for your fast and great answer, yes that was what i searched!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `values` and `einshaetzungen.alldata` in the wrong places

You want to assign the filtered list to a value then iterate through it.

```
<div ng-repeat="einschItem in values = (einschaetzungen.alldata| filter: { savedatum: lolatage[tagarrayindex].tagestring } | orderBy : '-savetimestamp')">

{{values.length}}
```

[Here is a similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/gwjhrqk4/)

This version works for older versions of angular.  For [v1.3.17-beta](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)+ you can use the `alias` formatting mentioned in Claies answer.

```
<div ng-repeat="einschItem in einschaetzungen.alldata | 
               filter: { savedatum: lolatage[tagarrayindex].tagestring } |
               orderBy : '-savetimestamp' 
               as filteredItems">

{{filteredItems.length}}
```